# crontab syntax query

Tags: syntax, cron

what does this crontab syntax mean

```
"*/15 * * * 2-5"
```

I thought it means it runs every 15 mins past every hour, from Tuesday to Saturday.
can I change that to:

```
"*/55 * * * 2-5"
```

that didn't seem to work for some reason.

Can you explain what is the */ at the beginning ?

Thanks

Comment: 2-5 is tuesday to friday

Comment: ah true, sorry it's 0 based, I fixed my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first example should be ok if you want it to run every 15 minutes. `2-5` on the 5th position is referring to Tuesday to Friday.

What do you want to accomplish with `*/55`?

A good syntax explanation can be found in [Wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Special_Characters)

> **Asterisk ( * )**
>
> The asterisk indicates that the cron
>   expression will match for all values
>   of the field; e.g., using an asterisk
>   in the 4th field (month) would
>   indicate every month.
>
> **Slash ( / )**
>
> Slashes are used to describe
>   increments of ranges. For example
>   3-59/15 in the 1st field (minutes)
>   would indicate the 3rd minute of the
>   hour and every 15 minutes thereafter.
>   The form "*/..." is equivalent to the
>   form "0-59/...".

Answer (score 2):

the `*/xx` means every xx time units.

In your example, `*/15` means every 15 minutes => :15 :30 :45

The `*/55` will be every 55 minutes, it will launch the script at 55 after each hour (10:55, 11:55, 12:55....)

Comment: I believe the */55 would launch, as you mention every 55 minutes, meaning 10:55, 11:50, 12:45, etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
"*/15 * * * 2-5"
```

The `*/15` does NOT mean it runs every 15 minutes past every hour... the `/15` is a step indicator, meaning it runs every 15 minutes (ie. 4 times an hour)

From the man page:

```
> man 5 crontab

Steps are also permitted after an asterisk, 
so if you want to say ``every two hours'', 
just use ``*/2''.
```

So only use the `*/` notation if you want to run something repeatedly, ie. multiple times an hour, multiple times a day, etc.

Peter

Answer (score 0):

contrary to folk lore, */xx does NOT mean every xx time units.

the / pattern means *approximately* every xx time units, but *not at the end of the range*.

it only works where xx is evenly divisible by the unit (i.e. for minutes, or seconds, that is only /2, /3, /4, /5, /6, /8, and /12)

for example */5 will repeat every 5 days most of the time except at the ends of months when it repeats after 1, 2, or 4 days, depending on the month and leapyear.

since 55 is so close to 60 it will actually work as you intend, but just by coincidence (because of rounding).  if you wrote */25 it would run twice an hour, at :25 and :50

Answer (score 0):

Jaime Guerroro's answer is close to the correct behaviour on RHEL 7.2
Here are my findings.
With cron entry as

```
*/55 * * * * /root/test.sh &>> /root/output.log
```

I get the behaviour

```
=== Start /root/test.sh Wed May 18 19:55:01  ===
=== Start /root/test.sh Wed May 18 20:00:01  ===
=== End /root/test.sh Wed May 18 20:02:35  ===
=== End /root/test.sh Wed May 18 20:03:44  ===
```

Explanation from wiki, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

> for example, entering */5 for the day field sometimes executes after
>   1, 2, or 3 days, depending on the month and leap year; this is because
>   cron is stateless (it does not remember the time of the last execution
>   nor count the difference between it and now, required for accurate
>   frequency counting-- instead, cron is a mere pattern-matcher).